# Find critical points of a function with two variables

Tags: functions

I need to find the critical points of function $x^3 + 3x^2y + 3x(y^2-1)$. So far I've found that the points are $(-2, 1)$, $(0, 1)$, $(0, -1)$ and $(2, -1)$ as correctly [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E3%20%2B%203x%5E2y%20%2B%203x%28y%5E2-1%29%20critical%20points) says but how can I find which one is max, min and neutral?

Comment: Find the hessian http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just substitute the $(x,y)$ values you found into the function, and check which one is the maximum and which one is the minimum.

Also, make sure that the value of $$f_{xx} f_{yy} - (f_{xy})^2$$ at that (x,y) is greater than zero. Otherwise, the point is an inflection point.

Comment: Btw, do you have a surface or volume in which you have to find the extrema? Because otherwise, you might have to rephrase your question to read 'local' maxima and 'local' minima.